# How to fix "dispatch is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a simple react-redux project that gets information about movies from the OMDB api based on search term provided by the user. I am  currently having trouble trying to get text typed into the searchbar to update the store value corresponding to the title of the film to search for. I'm fairly new to react and completely new to redux I've only finished one other redux project before and I set up my actions and reducers in the exact same way as last time but this time I'm running into "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function". This was not a problem I encountered in the previous project and my google searching has not been very helpful thus far.

I've searched this problem on google and only found a few results and none of them seem to be having the exact same issue as me, they involve using mapDispatchToProps which I'm not using inside of my connect function. Supposedly when you write a mapStateToProps like I have, dispatch should just be passed down as a prop to the connected component but whenever I try to access it I get the aforementioned "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function" error.

here is the index.js for my component

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import MovieSearch from './MovieSearchContainer';
import { 
  updateSearchTerm,
  getMovies
} from './movieSearchActions';

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    title: state.movieSearch.title,
    year: state.movieSearch.year,
    plot: state.movieSearch.plot,
    released: state.movieSearch.released,
    runtime: state.movieSearch.runtime,
    genre: state.movieSearch.genre,
    plot: state.movieSearch.plot,
    ratings: {
      IMDB: state.movieSearch.ratings.IMDB,
      Metascore: state.movieSearch.ratings.Metascore
    },
    posterUrl: state.movieSearch.posterUrl,
    cachedMovies: state.movieSearch.cachedMovies
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MovieSearch);
```

here is my action

```
export function updateSearchTerm(searchTerm){
  return {
    type: "UPDATE_SEARCH_TERM",
    payload: { searchTerm }
  }
}
```

here is my jsx component

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  updateSearchTerm,
  getMovies
} from './movieSearchActions';

export default class MovieSearchContainer extends React.Component 
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleUpdateSearchTerm = 
    this.handleUpdateSearchTerm.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdateSearchTerm(event){
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const { value } = event.target;
    dispatch(updateSearchTerm(value));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className='text-center'>Movie Finder</h1>
        <input type='text' className='col-sm-11' id='searchBar' 
        onChange={ this.handleUpdateSearchTerm }/>
        <button type='button' id='getMovies' className='col-sm- 
        1'>Go!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

MovieSearchContainer.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object
}
```

here is the reducer

```
export default function movieSearchReducer(state = defaultState, 
action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch(type){
    case 'UPDATE_SEARCH_TERM': {
      return {
        ...state,
        title: payload.title
      }
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

I expect changes in the searchbar on the component on the page to be reflected in the redux store, but instead I just get this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dispatch` prop is only available when you are directly interacting with the `redux-store`. When you define something like `mapDispatchToProps()` and pass it as the 2nd argument to `connect()`, `dispatch`, gets passed to `mapDispatchToProps()`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
      actionCreator: (arg) => {
         dispatch(actionCreator(arg))
      }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

If you dont want to define `mapDispatchToProps()`, you can effectively bind your action-creators by passing in an object to `connect()` as the 2nd argument. This  implicitly binds `dispatch` to the action-creators:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { updateSearchTerm, getMovies } from "./movieSearchActions";

class MovieSearchContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleUpdateSearchTerm = this.handleUpdateSearchTerm.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdateSearchTerm(event) {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.props.updateSearchTerm(value);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.movies);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-center">Movie Finder</h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="col-sm-11"
          id="searchBar"
          onChange={this.handleUpdateSearchTerm}
        />
        <button
          type="button"
          id="getMovies"
          className="col-sm- 
        1"
        >
          Go!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MovieSearchContainer.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
     title: state.movieSearch.title,
     year: state.movieSearch.year,
     plot: state.movieSearch.plot,
     released: state.movieSearch.released,
     runtime: state.movieSearch.runtime,
     genre: state.movieSearch.genre,
     plot: state.movieSearch.plot,
     ratings: {
     IMDB: state.movieSearch.ratings.IMDB,
       Metascore: state.movieSearch.ratings.Metascore
     },
     posterUrl: state.movieSearch.posterUrl,
     cachedMovies: state.movieSearch.cachedMovies
   };
 };


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    updateSearchTerm,
    getMovies
  }
)(MovieSearchContainer);
```

With that, you do not need to explicitly call dispatch to use your action-creator.  Simply use `this.props.nameOfActionCreator()`

See sandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-redux-7s1c0

Comment: I believe that's how I had it first, let me try that though and make sure edit: yeah that was how it was in my code and I still get the same error I must have mistyped it when posting the question but I'll fix it above, still getting the same error

Comment: @jayluvsdivn sweet! let me know how it goes :)

Comment: @khan is right, I was under the impression you already had this connected to redux. In order to get the dispatch prop, you still need to connect to your store.

Comment: I thought that was what the connect function was for inside of index.js?

Comment: @jayluvsdivn noo, you need to connect each component individually to the store :). See updated solution.

Comment: How would I do that? Or where should I look in the documentation if that's easier appreciate the help thanks, like what is missing?

Comment: @jayluvsdivn You do it the same way you would in the `index.js` component. I've updated my solution as well with the right approach :)

Comment: @jayluvsdivn Is there a reason why you separate the MovieSearchContainer into a different file? It looks like you arent doing anything in the index.js other than defining mapStateToProps, which should just be in the component jsx file.

Comment: Not any particular reason other than that's the same structure I used in the previous program and it worked, I'm assuming its probably incorrect to do it that way

Comment: @jayluvsdivn its just rather anti-pattern. But I dont think there's anything particularly wrong :). If you want to keep your original structure as is, all you need to do is bind the action-creators you imported to the connect(). I can show you.

Comment: I removed index.js and updated the jsx component to match what your solution showed but I'm still getting the same dispatch is not a function typerror

Comment: @jayluvsdivn sorry for the wild goose-chase. I'm a bit fatigued, but I've updated my solution and provided a sandbox to explain what is happening :)

Comment: this worked thank you soooooo much!! I've given your answer the checkmark :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should connect your component inside your jsx file. Then you can access with this.props.yourFunctionToDispatch

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  updateSearchTerm,
  getMovies
} from './movieSearchActions';

class MovieSearchContainer extends React.Component 
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleUpdateSearchTerm = 
    this.handleUpdateSearchTerm.bind(this);
  }

  handleUpdateSearchTerm(event){
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    const { value } = event.target;
    dispatch(updateSearchTerm(value));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className='text-center'>Movie Finder</h1>
        <input type='text' className='col-sm-11' id='searchBar' 
        onChange={ this.handleUpdateSearchTerm }/>
        <button type='button' id='getMovies' className='col-sm- 
        1'>Go!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    title: state.movieSearch.title,
    year: state.movieSearch.year,
    plot: state.movieSearch.plot,
    released: state.movieSearch.released,
    runtime: state.movieSearch.runtime,
    genre: state.movieSearch.genre,
    plot: state.movieSearch.plot,
    ratings: {
      IMDB: state.movieSearch.ratings.IMDB,
      Metascore: state.movieSearch.ratings.Metascore
    },
    posterUrl: state.movieSearch.posterUrl,
    cachedMovies: state.movieSearch.cachedMovies
  };
}

MovieSearchContainer.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {yourFunctionToDispatch})(MovieSearchContainer);
```